# How to enlarge images by clicking on them

Tags: javascript

This is edited based on the comments:
The goal: If the user clicks on an image it is enlarged. If the user clicks on an enlarged image, it returns to its original size.

Problem: This works only on the first image. How to make it work for all images?

```
<?php include('header.php'); ?>  
<style>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 45px;
}
table {
  border-spacing: 25px;
}
.center {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.pagination {
  display: inline-block;
}

.pagination a {
  color: black;
  float: left;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: background-color .3s;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.pagination a.active {2432
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid #4CAF50;
}
 
.pagination a:hover:not(.active) {background-color: #ddd;}
</style>
<style>
  .img-responsive {
    transition: all 0.25s ease
  }
  .enlarged {
    transform: scale(1.3);
  }
</style>
<?php
$enlarged=false;
 
?>
<div class="container text-center"> 
 
<table class="center" style="font-family:'Lato', 'Courier', 'monospace'" width="100%" height="100%" border="1">

<tr>
<td align="center" valign="middle"><img class="img-responsive" style="max-width:400px;width:100%"  
height="auto" src="xyz1.jpg" id="img1" onclick="enlargeImg()"
              /><br/>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td align="center" valign="middle"><img class="img-responsive" style="max-width:400px;width:100%"  height="auto" 
src="xyz2.jpg" id="img2" onclick="enlargeImg()"
/><br/>
</td>
</tr> 
</table><br/><br/> 
</div>

<p></p> 
<script>
 
  document.querySelector('.img-responsive').addEventListener('click', 
  function(){
    this.classList.toggle('enlarged');
  });
  
    </script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: it is not php, it is javascript

Comment: Sorry. Yes, you are correct.

Comment: `echo "..."` will produce a SyntaxError (unexpected string). `echo` isn't a valid keyword in JavaScript.

Comment: That could be `console.log("test");` in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to do this, IMO:

Add a CSS class that will enlarge the image

```
<style>
  .img-responsive {
    transition: all 0.25s ease
  }
  .enlarged {
    transform: scale(1.3);
  }
</style>
```

Use javascript to add or remove the class when the image is clicked

```
<script>
  Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('img-responsive')).forEach(
    function(element) {
      element.addEventListener('click', function(){
       this.classList.toggle('enlarged');
      });
    }
  );    
</script>
```

And remove the onlick from the img element in the HTML.  BTW, just noticed your img tag isn't closed in the HTML, so this is what you should use:

```
<tr>
<td align="center" valign="middle"><img class="img-responsive" style="max-width:400px;width:100%"  
height="auto" src="/images/xyz.jpg" id="img1" /> 
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Actually one problem: Please see the rewritten code above. Thank you!!!

Comment: I don't see any rewritten code - did you edit your question?   What's the problem you are having?

Comment: It's in the question at the top. Yes, I edited it.

Comment: Answer updated!  BTW, I still see that onclick attribute in the HTML of the images.